# Python ArgParse AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute

Tags: python, argparse

I have implemented argparse into a Python script like so:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-s", "--shortterm", help="Tweets top information from the past month", default="track",
                    choices=choices, dest="shortterm")
parser.add_argument("-m", "--mediumterm", help="Tweets top information from the past 6 months", default="track",
                    choices=choices)
parser.add_argument("-l", "--longterm", help="Tweets top information from the past few years", default="track",
                    choices=choices)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Which I then check args for things the user could have entered or selected, like so:

```
if args.mediumterm:
    if args.mediumterm == "all":
        get_top_tracks(medium_term)
        get_top_artists(medium_term)
    else:
        if args == "track":
            get_top_tracks(medium_term)
        elif args == "artist":
            get_top_artists(medium_term)
```

When I run the script with the following command:

```
python top_tracks_artists_spotify_time.py --mediumterm all
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "top_tracks_artists_spotify_time.py", line 127, in <module>
if args.mediumterm:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mediumterm'
```

The annoying thing is running:

```
python top_tracks_artists_spotify_time.py --shortterm all
```

runs the script successfully.

EDIT: I have added dest="mediumterm" to the argparse to no avail

Comment: where/how are you defining `args`?

Comment: `print` to see what you are looking for: `print(args)` `print(args.__dict__)` `print(dir(args))`

Comment: @aydow added the code. it has always been there, just not copied and pasted into the question by mistake

Comment: @JacobIRR I added all three bits of code into the script and mediumterm appears each time, so it is definitely in the args. The same with shortterm, which when I run the shortterm arg the script runs

Comment: args is a string in this context: `args.mediumterm` so I don't understand how that is possible. At some point you are transforming args from a dict/object into a string.

Comment: Search for `args =` before the line 127 and make sure you're not overwriting it.

Comment: Your `dest` arguments are pointless (the default `dest` is the long name of the switch, so your `dest` is redundant). As @zwer says, you've got somewhere where you reassign `args` to a `str`, so it is no longer an `argparse` namespace object; it's clearly in a conditional path since it doesn't always occur. You need to provide a [MCVE] that actually demonstrates the problem for us to provide anything further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your processing code, after `args = parser.parse_args()` should look something like:

```
term = args.mediumterm
if term:
    if term == "all":
        get_top_tracks(term)     # unless medium_term is defined else where
        get_top_artists(term)
    else:
        if term == "track":
            get_top_tracks(term)
        elif term == "artist":
            get_top_artists(term)
```

Similarly for `shortterm` and `longterm`.  Once created by `parse_args`, `args` should not be reassigned (it will only confuse you and your readers).

Comment: This makes sense and is systematically a better way to do it it seems. Thanks